# Access Teamcity to Gitlab repository (Fetch URL)

Tags: url, gitlab, fetch, teamcity

Access to the GitLab CE repository through TeamCity is limited to using only `ssh` key -  login and password does not accept.

```
Error `Connection refused`
```

GitLab allow to log in using browser by ssh, access key and username/password.

Comment: So why don’t you use SSH?

Comment: If you have successfully connected to repository via ssh, it is not possible to use Commit Status Publisher because it uses the URL specified in the Fetch URL field, and can only connect using access token, which is strange (why not use an already configured ssh authorization). Yes, and now I noticed that when you create a new build configuration when you select GitLab as VCS, and press Sing in to GitLab, you get An error has occurred
The redirect URI included is not valid. (https://gitlab.prod.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=9e99f82a8c69b43)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but you can close the task. The problem was in the proxy server used in the company, not the NGINX in GitLab Omnibus package. On the server  TeamCity in system variables (TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS) settings did not specify an exception for resources that do not use the domain, namely the value of  -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.prod.com since the site with GitLab https://gitlab.prod.com

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the wrong value system var `TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` on master server TeamCity
My GitLab CE is located at https://gitlab.org.com, but the value was not specified by `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.org.com` to exclude local addresses

That's all